# Java/Android Studio - Covariant Return Type - Method in "subclass" clashes with method in "baseclass": attempting to use incompatible return type

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I am currently trying to apply a covariant return type in the following situation (code is truncated heavily for relevance):

**Attribute class:**

```
  public abstract class Attribute
    {
         protected Number value;
         public Attribute(Number initialValue)  
         {     this.value = initialValue;}

         public abstract Number getValue();
    }
```

**DoubleAttribute class:**

```
  public class DoubleAttribute extends Attribute
        {
             public DoubleAttribute(double initialValue)  
             {     super(initialValue);}

             @Override     
             public double getValue() //The error shows on 'double'
             {     return this.value.doubleValue();}
        }
```

Sadly, Android Studio is not allowing me to change the return type of the subclass `DoubleAttribute` from `Number` to `double`.

Android Studio is currently giving me the following error:

`'getValue() in "attributes.DoubleAttribute" clashes with 'getValue()' in 'attributes.Attribute'; attempting to use incompatible return type.`

I am currently at a loss for ideas as to what i am doing wrong. Every covariant return type example that i've sought on Google tells me that this should work, as the `double` class is a subclass of `Number`.

If anyone could help me by pointing out why Android Studio is telling me that this isn't allowed i would be very grateful.

On a side note, i am not entirely sure as to if the approach i am taking is correct in the first place. I am currently measuring attributes that can either be of `String` type, `double` type, `long` type or `int` type and subsequently storing them in a SQLite table. At first i declared the `value` variable as a String and just parsed in a String representation of a double/float/int/long. I found, however, that this required loads of excess casting and type checking and sought for an alternative solution, but i am still doubting if my current inheritance solution is an optimal one.

If anyone could share their insights on this matter as well, i would be even more grateful.

Thanks in advance for any effort, and if more of the written code is required i'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not return a `Double`class. You return a primitive double. A primitive type can not be a subclass of an object.

```
public double getValue() //The error shows on 'double'
{
    return this.value.doubleValue();
}
```

change to (Uppercase D)

```
public Double getValue() //The error shows on 'double'
{
     return this.value;
}
```

Comment: That did it thanks alot! Now is there any efficient way of determining what kind of variable came back when calling `Attribute a = new DoubleAttribute(20.0d); a.getValue()`. I ask this because when i want to insert the value in my SQLite Database, i have to put it in to a `ContentValues` object using `ContentValues.put(key, value)`. However, this `put(key, value)` method only takes (in addition to others) subclasses of `Number` like `long` and `double`, but not `Number`. How would one go about doing this without, again, resorting to excessive type checking and casting? Thanks again in advance!